# why the sum of "Functions With Most Individual Work" can't be more than 100%?

Tags: visual-studio, profiling

I'm using VS2010 built-in profilier
My application contains three threads.
One of the thread is really simple:

```
while (true)
    if (something) {
        // blah blah, very fast and rarely occuring thing
    }
    Thread.sleep(1000);
}
```

Visual Studio reports that Thread.sleep takes 36% of the program time.
The question is "why not ~100% of the time?" Why `Main` methods takes 40% of the time, I definitely was inside this method durring application execution from start to end.

[image]

Do profiler devides the result to the number of the threads?

On my another thread I've observed that method takes 34% of the time.
What does it mean? Does it mean that it works only 34% of the time or it works almost all the time?

In my opinion if I have three threads that run in parallel, and if I sum methods time I should get 300% (if application runs for 10 seconds for example, this means that each thread runs for 10 seconds, and if there are 3 threads - it would be 30 seconds totally)

Answer (score 1):

The question is *what* do you measuring and *how* you do it. From your question I'm unable to repeat your experience actually...

`Thread.Sleep()` call takes very small amount of time itself. Its task is to call native function from WinAPI that will command scheduler (responsible for dividing processor time between threads) that user thread it was called from should not be scheduled for the next second at all. After that this thread doesn't receive processor time until this second is over.

But thread do not takes any bit of processor time in that state. I'm not sure how this situation is reported by profiler.

---

Here is the code I was experimenting with:

```
internal class Program
{
    private static int x = 0;

    private static void A()
    {
        // Just to have something in the profiler here
        Console.WriteLine("A");
    }

    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var t = new Thread(() => { while (x == 0) Thread.MemoryBarrier(); });
        t.Start();

        while (true)
        {
            if (DateTime.Now.Millisecond%3 == 0)
                A();

            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: profilier instruments code measuring when the function is entered and exit, those profiler thinks that Thread.Sleep(1000) takes 1 second. it doesn't matter what happens inside Thread.Sleep(1000)

Comment: Just tested similar code. With instrumentation I have 99.9% in `Thread.Sleep()` as expected. Will try with some additional threads.

Comment: @javapowered: Obviously, you're right. VS profiler normalizes results to 100%. When I added second thread with `new Thread(() => { while (x == 0) Thread.MemoryBarrier(); }).Start()` results became 47% vs 53% between anonymous lambda (evidently it is thread's routine) and `Thread.Sleep()`.

Comment: Hm thanks for tests! Now the question is - how to force VS to show "by thread" or "per thread" statistics....

Comment: To view "by thread" statistics "Call Tree" view may be useful.. But it is not clear still why some threads take more time than others. If all thread started and finished at the same time, I expect they were executing for the same amount of time... I will make tests tomorrow holding stopwatch in hands :)

Comment: to understand how often my method is called I'm using "hand stopwatch" to measure how long the program is run and "Elapsed Inclusive Time", also "Avg. Elapsed Inclusive Time" and "Numbver of Calls" metrics are usefull. For example if program were run for 60 seconds and method was called 60 times averaging 1 second per call - then method was executing 100% of the time. This resolves my issue.